# Configuring SSL for Jetty in http4k

Tags: ssl, kotlin, jetty, http4k

I am trying to make my http4k REST API require SSL but I can't manage to figure out how to configure Jetty for SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it supports multiple backends, http4k doesn't come with any inbuilt APIs to implement SSL. Instead, you implement your own custom version of the `Jetty` ServerConfig interface so configure the server as required. As a template you can use the one here:

https://github.com/http4k/http4k/blob/master/http4k-server-jetty/src/main/kotlin/org/http4k/server/jetty.kt